# Looking for the english translation of Serre's mass formula

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic, local-field

I am looking for an English translation of the paper by Serre titled:

Une "formule de masse'' pour les extensions totalement ramifiées de degré donné d'un corps local

Could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: I hope you find it...but at this paper's level (graduate school and beyond), if you don't find it then you'll have to translate it by yourself. Grab your favourite dictionary and...good luck!

Comment: I find that Serre's papers are usually very readable, with mild help from Google translate. This [French mathematics dictionary](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~kwlan/documents/french-glossary.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: The bigger problem though, is that even the French version is not available online.

Comment: I can't even find a Frence version of this paper, though many other papers have cited this paper.